# add variable as a collection reference in query firestore data

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am retrieving data from firebase firestore as in this code :

```
    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("docs").orderBy("timeStamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<download> docsFirestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<download>()
            .setQuery(query, download.class)
            .build();
```

i've tried to use a string as

```
String s="docs";
firebaseFirestore.collection(" "+s)...
```

but it doesn't show anything. how to do this in a better way?

Comment: It should be possible to use just `firebaseFirestore.collection(s)...`. Do you have any errors on this?

Comment: it just does not retrieve the data if I do it in this way